# Trying to Load a Contact in Metadata through Python and ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, metadata

Attempting to create a metadata contact and then use that contact to load in to the Resource Citation Contact and the Metadata Citation Contact metadata fields. The metadata library has an element in the form of:

```
"citation_contact": {
        "path": "dataIdInfo/idCitation/citRespParty",
        "type": "parent_item",
        "elements": contact_elements},
```

But I can not seem to properly connect this element "citation_contact" to the new contact that I defined earlier in the same script. In that script, I define a new contact as:

```
contact = metadata.point_of_contact
contact_name = metadata.point_of_contact.contact_name
metadata.point_of_contact.contact_name = "Bob Smith"
```

How do I load "Bob Smith" into either Citation Contact field?

Here is the element in the library for the contact:

```
"role": {
        "path": "role/RoleCd",
        "type": "attribute",
        "key": "value",
        "values": [("resource provider", "001"),
                   ("custodian", "002"),
                   ("owner", "003"),
                   ("user", "004"),
                   ("distributer", "005"),
                   ("originator", "006"),
                   ("point of contact", "007"),
                   ("principal investigator", "008"),
                   ("processor", "009"),
                   ("publisher", "010"),
                   ("author", "011")]},

    "contact_name": {
        "path": "rpIndName",
        "type": "string"},
```

Comment: At the moment you appear to be presenting a copy/paste of a few lines from your code rather than a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck. What code creates your metadata object?